# postgres array range notation with jooq

Tags: postgresql, jooq

in my postgres database i have an array of jsons (`json[]`) to keep track of errors in the form of json objects. if an update comes in i want to append the latest error to that array but only keep the latest 5 errors (all sql is simplified):

```
update dc
set 
    error_history           =
        array_append(dc.error_history[array_length(dc.error_history, 1) - 4:array_length(dc.error_history, 1)+1], cast('{"blah": 6}' as json))
where dc.id = 'f57520db-5b03-4586-8e77-284ed2dca6b1'
;
```

this works fine in native sql, i tried to replicate this in jooq as follows:

```
.set(dc.ERROR_HISTORY,
    field("array_append(dc.error_history[array_length(dc.error_history, 1) - 4:array_length(dc.error_history, 1) + 1], cast('{0}' as json))", dc.ERROR_HISTORY.getType(), latestError)
);
```

but it seems the `:` causes the library to think that there is a bind parameter there. the generated sql is:

```
array_append(dc.error_history[array_length(dc.error_history, 1) - 4?(dc.error_history, 1) + 1], cast('{0}' as json)
```

and the error i get is

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$5"
```

which i totally agree with :D

is there some way to escape the `:` in the java code or is there a better way to do this?

edit:
i have also tried just to remove the first element upon updating using the `arrayRemove` function but that also didn't work because it doesn't work by index but by element and postgres doesn't know how to check json elements for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg, the answer was really simple :D

```
field("array_append(dc.error_history[array_length(dc.error_history, 1) - 4 : array_length(dc.error_history, 1) + 1], cast({0} as json))", dc.ERROR_HISTORY.getType(), latestError)
```

just add spaces around the colon and it works correctly. note that i made another mistake by putting single quotes around `{0}`, because the `latestError` object is already of type `JSON`.

Comment: This works because it breaks jOOQ's assumption that `:xyz` are named parameter literals, which they are in many dialects (but not PG, where the syntax is `$xyz`)

Comment: Yes i realized that immediately afterwards, thanks for answering :)